# Unable to use Kubernetes and Jackson 2 API plugins simuntaneously at Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes

I am trying to deploy my web application usin Kubernetes at Jenkins, but the `manifest.yml` is not being properly read, as I constantly get the following error logs:

```
 ERROR: Can't construct a java object for tag:yaml.org,2002:io.kubernetes.client.openapi.models.V1Deployment; exception=Class not found: io.kubernetes.client.openapi.models.V1Deployment
 in 'reader', line 1, column 1:
    apiVersion: v1
    ^
```

For what I've read in other entries, this seems to be an issue with the latest versions of the Jackson API plugin. Due to this, I've tried to downgrade this plugin, but this does not seem to be possible, as In have several plugins installed that require the latest Jackson 2 API plugin version, which is the reason why I get an error when trying to downgrade.

Therefore, I'd like to know if I have any alternative to fix this problem when parsing the `manifest.yml` rather thar diwngrading every dependent plugin one by one.